# Tensorflow basic printing outputs an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying tensorflow for first time!
my code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess=tf.Session()
hello=tf.constant('Hello!')
print(sess.run(hello))
```

But it outputs an error. I don't know how to solve it, but I don't want to install another tensorflow version. I use python 3.6 and tensorflow 2.1.0

I have to write more, cause I can't post it, and I don't know what to write.

Here is the full output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Error en una rutina de inicialización de biblioteca de vínculos dinámicos (DLL).

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\Desktop\Hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Error en una rutina de inicialización de biblioteca de vínculos dinámicos (DLL).


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Please add the *entire stack trace* (as the message above suggests) and the exact command line used to run the program to your question. Also, how did you install tensorflow? Try using a *virtualenv*. If you still get the error, add the exact commands you used for setting up the virtual environment.

Comment: @pcarter I just edited the post

Comment: I guess it is got to do with `protobuf` version, what version do you have?

Comment: @learner 3.11.3

Comment: Try downgrading it to `3.6.0`. Doing this solved the issue in TF v1. If this doesn't work, you can work your way upwards from here

Comment: @learner I installed protobuf 3.6.1, cause the 3.6.0 was incompatible. Outputs the same error

Answer (score 0):

tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session instead. Please refer code below

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
  hello=tf.constant('Hello!')
  result = sess.run(hello)
  print(result)
```

Output:

```
2.1.0
b'Hello!'
```